# Is Hinduism related to Jainism?

Tags: shiva, jainism

I see a lot of stuff that sort of show that Jainism is related to Hinduism.For example, [Was Parsvanatha, the 23rd tirthankara of Jainism, an avatar of Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14540/was-parsvanatha-the-23rd-tirthankara-of-jainism-an-avatar-of-lord-shiva) Asks if Parsvanath, the 23rd tirthankara of Jainism was an avatar of Lord Shiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better question to ask would be 'Is Jainism related to Hinduism' ?
because Jainism came later.

Yes, it is related.

Jainism falls under Nastika school of thought because they don't accept the authority of Vedas.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80stika_and_n%C4%81stika

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: Isn't that a little pedantic, to consider which came first? The more important question to me, is how they mutually influenced each other

Comment: @MoziburUllah, again, they did not 'mutually' influence one another, because Jainism is just an offshoot of Hinduism. Hinduism influenced Jainism, not the other way around.

Comment: @Mozibur Ullah Jainism isn't an offshoot of the Vedic Religion it is simply a rejection of it hence it's not part of this Hinduism. While some Jain characters are syncretized into later scriptures that affirm authority of the Vedas ie Puranas there wasn't much philosophical syncretism. Jains did make their versions of Ramayana and Mahabharata however.